# Is an extended spring gain mass from potential energy?

Tags: special-relativity, potential-energy, spring, mass-energy

Is it true that when a spring is extended, potential energy is stored in spring and result in gain of mass of the spring?

Comment: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/212082/does-the-rest-mass-energy-include-the-potential-energy-of-the-particle i think the above issue has been amply explained in the previous thread.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, spring mass will increase but in very very small amount.

As per [Mass energy equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass%E2%80%93energy_equivalence) the amount of mass gain will be(E=mc2):

m= E/C2

**for example** if spring have store 1 Joule of potential energy when it is extended then the increased mass will be:

m =1/299792458= 3.33564095198152**e-9**

Comment: i think its not proper to calculate changes in the   mass of a body in a field or in a system having potential energy...otherwise  our mass will change if we go to top floor of my apartment!

Comment: @drvrm Please check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass%E2%80%93energy_equivalence read  **strict mass–energy equivalence** ,  yes it will change our mass.

Comment: @ editinit .. i think you are correct .. in the limiting cases of  very small changes in the mass of a system .. one can visualize it.